# pentaho data integration - cant connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection, pentaho, pdi

anyone can help me to resolve my problem?

i can't connect from pentaho to mysql

```
Error connecting to database [mysql - simpeg] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
```

i already add at \pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342 PENTAHO\data-integration\lib

> com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar

and i restart my PDI, when i try again, the problem is same.

please help me. Thanks

Comment: Pentaho shouldn't use `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`, that is an extremely old driver name that was deprecated over a decade ago AFAIK. That said, you could try to upgrade to a newer version of the MySQL Connector/J driver (5.1.5 is pretty old). Do make sure to use a 5.1.x version of the driver, because the `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` no longer exists in the 8.0.x drivers. Also check the Pentaho documentation for the correct location of the driver jar.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho Data Integration uses `mysql-connector-java-5.x.xx-bin.jar` to connect MySQL for example `mysql-connector-java-5.1.49-bin.jar` and you can download MySQL driver from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) also you can find PDI's JDBC Drivers Reference from [here](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.2/Setup/JDBC_Drivers_Reference#MySQL)